# How to join two tables properly?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two table which works perfectly on their own. Here I select all of my traffic sources which corresponds to userID `12` who purchased something on my homepage.

```
SELECT date, trafficSource.A, trafficSource.B, trafficSource.C,hits.transaction.BuyID 
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([25.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03'), TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03')))
WHERE hits.transaction.BuyID  = '12'
```

where I get:

```
trafficSource.A,trafficSource.B,trafficSource.C,hits.transaction.BuyID 
    a                 b                 c            12
```

In my second table I select those traffic Sources meeting specific criteria:

```
SELECT trafficSource.A, trafficSource.B, trafficSource.C
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([25.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03')
WHERE trafficSource.source = 'specific criteria'
```

Now I would like to produce a table which contains information about all `BuyIDs` and there corresponding traffic sources:

```
SELECT trafficSource.A, trafficSource.B, trafficSource.C,hits.transaction.BuyID 
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([25.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03'), TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03'))) AS result
JOIN (SELECT hits.transaction.BuyID 
      FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([25.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03'), TIMESTAMP('2015-09-03'))))AS results
      ON result.hits.transaction.BuyID =results.hits.transaction.BuyID
```

getting:

```
Error: 0.0 - 0.0: Ambiguous field reference transaction.BuyID 

query invalidQuery. 0.0 - 0.0: Ambiguous field reference transaction.BuyID
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need to join at all, if you simply want to select *all* BuyIDs and their corresponding traffic sources. In other words, what is the relation between the first to queries you give (with criteria) and the joined query?

Comment: The Problem is, that if I `Select` just all `BuyIDs`  and corresponding `traffic sources` I'll get a table with huge amount of `NA` in `BuyIDs` . Taking the joint would make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be the case is that you're selecting the column transaction.BuyID, but it is present in both of the tables you join ('result' and 'results'), so BigQuery doesn't know which one you want. (Even though the values happen to be the same because that's how you define your join.) Select 'result.hits.transaction.BuyID' instead.

Comment: Im sorry I just adjusted the query. I forgot `hits`

Comment: Ok, but it's still ambiguous, hits.transaction.BuyID is present in both result and results.

Comment: Adjusting `JOIN (SELECT hits.transaction.BuyID` to `JOIN (SELECT result.hits.transaction.BuyID` gives 
`Error: Field 'result.hits.transaction.BuyID' not found.`

`query invalidQuery. Field 'result.hits.transaction.BuyID' not found.`

Comment: same `error`  here `Select trafficSource.A, trafficSource.B, trafficSource.C,result.hits.transaction.BuyID`

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting when you change hits.transaction.BuyID to result.hits.transaction.BuyID in the top-most select statement? (So *not* the subselect in the join.)

Comment: `Error: Field 'result.hits.transaction.BuyID' not found on either side of the JOIN`

`query invalidQuery. Field 'result.hits.transaction.BuyID' not found on either side of the JOIN`

Comment: Strange that you get that error, since you are joining on that field. I can't tell you more without knowing the column structure of the underlying tables, but you could try giving the columns in your subselects aliases and referencing those in the top query.